# Count amount of decimal places (Swift)

Tags: swift, calculator, rounding

I want to round a Double to a specific amount of decimal places.
I want it to be rounded to the exact length of itself.

For example "1.23" should stay "1.23", "1.230" instead should change to "1.23" etc.

I am trying to count the decimal places and round the Double with that value.

I've been trying around in Playground, but somehow Swift always rounds and uses unneeded decimal places.

Here's what I got so far

```
var someDouble:Double
var someString:String
var lenghtInt:Int



someDouble = 42.123                                 // create a float

someDouble = someDouble % 1                         // get rid of everything infront of the comma

someString = NSString(format: "%f", someDouble)     // format float into string

lenghtInt = someString.utf16Count - 2               // count lenght, substract 2 (for "0" & ".")
```

It tells me I have 6 decimal places because it puts "000" at the end.

How do I fix this?

By the way:

Maybe I'm thinking completely wrong. The purpose of all of that is to display a Float/Double in a label but without the unneeded decimal places. It should work for any given number.
Hopefully You guys have an answer for me! :)

Thank You in advance

Niklas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
let s1 = String(format: "%.19g", 1.2345) // 1.2345
```

Not sure if swift printf supports '%g' though.

Edit: the 19 is based on the precision of a double, to display all (nonzero) digits, but not get `...0001` at the end. '%g' is the printf format specifier for 'natural' representation of floating point numbers.

Comment: %.g does work! What does it stand for?  It is working with %.7g! Thanks a lot

Comment: @NiklasHein, '%g' doesn't stand for anything, etymology is "%e,%f,%g", around "float". The '.N' is the field width, which is supposed to be the number of characters in the output, but for '%f' &c is actually for like "the number of digits printed, except not counting a leading zero" which is... less useful.

Comment: @NiklasHein, on further investigation, 'exponential', 'float', and 'general' are indicated, but I'm fairly certain at least the latter was a post-hoc fabrication.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let s1 = String(format: "%.2f", 1.2345) // 1.23
let s2 = String(format: "%.2f", 1.2) // 1.20
let s3 = String(format: "%.2f", 42.1239420000) // 42.12
```

Comment: This will work for Floats with 2 decimal Places, but not for any other then. I want it to work with any Float possible.

Comment: That's what you told you want to do. Cut to 2 decimal places.

Comment: this was only an example. I want it to work even if the Float is e.g 42.1239420000

Comment: Using %g instead of %f does not return what you asked for. So I don't understand what you wanted.

Comment: @ThomasKilian the OP is saying that if it is `1.230`, it would change to `1.23`. However, if it is `1.23459000`, it would change to `1.23459`. OP wants to drop any trailing 0's but keep all other significant digits.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, I think what they asked for was "no trailing zeros". '%g' still gets ugly sometimes, but it's usually less so than '%f'.

Comment: Maybe he meant to ask that, but actually he did not. Anyway. Next question please ;-)